# The best way to store given lat, long and address in mongo db such that finding address for a given lat, long is fast

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, reverse-geocoding

I am scratching my head around from past two days to get it right.
I have a live data set of around 20M lat, long and address. Now, I want to store them in MongoDB such that query to find the address for a given lat, long is fast.
Some of the solutions that I found on MongoDB are :

1. index loc with 2dsphere.

but how good is find query for an **exact match** of lat, long?

2. If not using 2dsphere then what is the best way to store lat, long so that keep storage and index size at the minimum and get the performance.

Comment: It's sort of opinion based except for "fact" that GeoJSON support is actually more widely adopted and standard in MongoDB operations. Legacy pairs does not work so well with everything. Outside of that though you're getting a bit broad.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB uses a [GeoHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) and a B-tree internally for its `2dsphere` indices, which provides very fast area lookups using [`$near`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) and [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/); you can use `$minDistance` and `$maxDistance` of 0 for exact matches but you may want to use a `$maxDistance` of 1 if you're worried about issues relating to floating point precision. In many cases it can be important to `limit(1)` your results if they are densely distributed in some places, although for street addresses that should not be an issue. On my dev machine I can query a collection with 40 million polygons, totalling nearly 50GB of data, in 300-400 ms.

Comment: +1 for Mentioning GeoHash. Its fine what you have mentioned but isn't it overkill? I just need the address on a exact lat,long.  I have read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-a-2d-index/#exact-matches-on-a-flat-surface